# How can you rotate the lower body

Tags: unity-game-engine, inverse-kinematics

how can you rotate the lower body? if you rotate the Hips object, then the entire object rotates, but it remains only to rotate the legs one by one, so that the lower part can be rotated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8eIh.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate separate parts of your character in **Mecanim** you have to separate the body parts of your asset's animation avatar with **Avatar Masks**. Masking off your character's lower body allows you to animate it with a separate mecanim layer independent of your main animation control layer. Unity documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/class-AvatarMask.html